# Passing ViewData to Partial View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, renderpartial, viewdata

Controller

```
 IEnumerable<AvgPosGAFields> _myList = helper.ConvertToListAvgPosGa(locDataSetGACampaigns.Tables[0]);        
 ViewData["hourlydata"] = _myList;
```

i want to use pass this ViewData to my partial to fill a table i am using renderpartial to render my partial my. 
How can i pass this ViewData ? and how can i use foreach on it??

Main View:

```
 Html.RenderPartial( "HourlyDetails",new ViewDataDictionary { { "hourlydata", 0 } } );
```

Partial View contains a table which is to be filled by the model in ViewData

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative I would recommend switching `ViewData` to use View Models as they're strongly typed instead.

You could do this in the following way:

**Create a View Model**

```
public class AViewModel
{
  public IEnumerable<AvgPosGAFields> HourlyData { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
var model = new AViewModel();
model.HourlyData = helper.ConvertToListAvgPosGa(locDataSetGACampaigns.Tables[0]);

return View(model);
```

The above assumes your method returns an `IEnumerable<AvgPosGAFields>`.

**View**

Add a model reference at the top an then pass the model into your partial as follows:

```
@model AViewModel
...
@Html.Partial("HourlyDetails", Model.HourlyData)
```

**Partial View**

Also add the model reference to the top of your partial view i.e.

```
@model IEnumerable<AvgPosGAFields>
```

This means you will be able to loop your model in the partial as follows:

```
@foreach(var avgPosGAField in Model)
{
      @avgPosGAField.FooProperty
}
```

Comment: Yes. Passing elements of a collection to partial views is a strong sign that it is time to use a view model with strongly typed partials.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Html.Action()` in controller:

```
public ActionResult RenderAction()
{
   //....
   IEnumerable<AvgPosGAFields> _myList = helper.ConvertToListAvgPosGa(locDataSetGACampaigns.Tables[0]);        

   return PartialView( _myList );
}
```

And call it from other view you want:

```
@Html.Action("RenderAction", "Controller")
```

And in `RenderAction` view, use foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you somehow accidently or partly on purpose overwrite the full ViewData, my problem was overwriting the ViewData for templating, without realizing the rest of the ViewData was gone.

```
@Html.Partial("_EmployeeFormContent", @Model.Employee, new ViewDataDictionary() { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = nameof(Model.Employee) } })
```

Adding the current `ViewData` to the new `ViewDataDictionary` fixed it:

```
    @Html.Partial("_EmployeeFormContent", @Model.Employee, new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = nameof(Model.Employee) } })
```

Answer (score 0):

use a viewbag instead of viewdata

```cs
IEnumerable<AvgPosGAFields> _myList = helper.ConvertToListAvgPosGa(locDataSetGACampaigns.Tables[0]);
ViewData["hourlydata"] = _myList;
```

so try

```
ViewBag.hourlydata = _myList;
```

then even if it does not work, try this solution
http://www.codenoevil.com/pass-additional-viewdata-asp-net-mvc-4/